# Scroll to section of another page

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to navigate to specific page on specific section. Here is the code.

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'get',
     url: 'profile.php',
     cache: false,
     dataType: 'json',
     data: '&uid=' +uid,
     success: function(data) {
         //   console.log =data;
         if(data.first != 'yes'){
             alert('Your profile is incomplete. Redirecting to update the profile.');
             location.href = "./add_resume.php";
         }else if(data.two != 'yes'){
             alert('Your profile is incomplete. Redirecting to update the profile.');
             location.href = "./edit_resume.php#education";
         }else if(data.third != 'yes'){
             alert('Your profile is incomplete. Redirecting to update the profile.');
             location.href = "./edit_resume.php#experience";
         }else if(data.four != 'yes'){
             alert('Your profile is incomplete. Redirecting to update the profile.');
             location.href = "./edit_resume.php#skillset";
         }else if(data.five != 'yes'){
 
         }else if(data.six != 'yes'){
             alert('Your profile is incomplete. Redirecting to update the profile.');
             location.href = "./edit_resume.php#personal";
         }else  if(data.seven != 'yes'){
             alert('Your profile is incomplete. Redirecting to update the profile.');
             location.href = "./edit_resume.php#contact";
         }else{
             alert('Need to create a new profile.');  
         }
```

It is redirecting to specific page but not on specific section.

What can I do now?

Some codes from Edit resume file:

```
<section id="experience" class="block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 wow fadeInRight animated">
```

Comment: edit_resume.php page should have divs with diferent id (contact, personal,skillset,etc), right?

Comment: Do the elements on the page you want to redirect to have IDs that match the code above? For example, do you have an element with an ID of contact (`id="contact"`) to match `./edit_resume.php#contact`?

Comment: Actually they do have id in edit_resume.php.

Comment: Do you have any js scroll plugin or javascript ```scrollToTop``` kind of code added to your webpage?